# UIStepperButtom Image change (+ and -)

Tags: ios, uistepper

I know this question is quite funny, but want to give a try is it possible to change the `UIStepper` image **`+`** and **`-`** image to some other image **`x.png`** and **`y.png`**?

Answer (score 1):

In [iOS 6](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/decrementImageForState%3a) it is possible but in earlier versions not having this feature.
These are the methods available

1. [– backgroundImageForState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/backgroundImageForState%3a)
2. [– setBackgroundImage:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/setBackgroundImage%3aforState%3a)
3. [– decrementImageForState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/decrementImageForState%3a)
4. [– setDecrementImage:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/setDecrementImage%3aforState%3a)
5. [– dividerImageForLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/dividerImageForLeftSegmentState%3arightSegmentState%3a)
6. [– setDividerImage:forLeftSegmentState:rightSegmentState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/setDividerImage%3aforLeftSegmentState%3arightSegmentState%3a)
7. [– incrementImageForState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/incrementImageForState%3a)
8. [– setIncrementImage:forState:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIStepper/setIncrementImage%3aforState%3a)

if you want to change the appearence of the the stepper then use below code.

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"]  forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIStepper class], nil] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"disabled.png"]  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Comment: Now both Question and Answer are looking beautiful ;)